# Is there a graph component that lets me specify x- and y-axis to be positioned in an other grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, dynamic-data-display

I am working on a projekt to display data in form of a graph. In order for me to do what i want to do i need a graph or chart component that lets me move the x- and y-axis to different grids.

To clarify:
My graph should consist of 3 different parts.
1: The actual graph that displays the line.
2: The y-axis.
3: The x-axis.

I want to put the graph (1) in one grid, the y-axis (2) inside an other grid and the x-axis (3) inside a third grid.

I have looked at WPF-Toolkit and Data Driven Documents (D3) but I can not figure out a way to split these 3 parts in the way that I have described here.

Is it possible to use WPF-Toolkit or D3 to achieve this or is there an other component that lets me do this?

The component does not need to be free but I should be able to modify it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Syncfusion components for WPF, they have a very good Chart component

Comment: Ok, will check it out

Comment: Hi, I have now looked at Synfusion and I cant find anything that lets you split up x- and y-axis from the graph. If you could provide a link or some code that explains how to do this that whould be very appreciated.

Comment: check out the online documentation under Axis menu http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf

Comment: I have looked there and cant find anything. What am I missing?

Comment: you can use nested charts, the online documentation isn't rich.